# Developing a Visual Kotlin Application in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: android, kotlin, intellij-idea

I am starting to learn Kotlin and I want to develop a visual Kotlin application for Android, and I am using IntelliJ Idea. I haven't really found any tutorials on how to use IntelliJ to develop *visual* Kotlin applications, I have found many on how to develop them with Android Studio, but I started with IntelliJ and would rather stick with it than learning a new one. Is there a way to develop visual Kotlin applications in IntelliJ Idea or do I have to switch to Android Studio?

Comment: My advice is to just install Android Studio and use it. Fewer issues. I used to use IntellJ IDEA for my Android development but it occasionally wasted my time, like once the Android plugin lagged Android Studio on fixing a bug that was preventing my build. It’s also just kind of a pain to get the SDK set up correctly if you don’t do it using Android Studio. I refresh my OS installation occasionally so it saves a lot of time. There is nothing to learn if you’re already familiar with IntelliJ since Android Studio is a minor fork of IntellJ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't lose anything switching to Android Studio, because it's built on a same platform core as intellij idea.

But there should probably be a way, probably you have to set everything up in:
`Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Android SDK`

Then in top menu bar
`Tools -> Android` you will have an AVD and SDK managers.

[Full guide for setting project android up in Intellij Idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/create-your-first-android-application.html)